# JSONP in Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, jsonp

I want to get data from my Database into my Angluar.js.

So i created a php file, which selects my data.
I read that i have to use jsonp, elsewhise i will not get the data.

data.php

```
<?php 
    $db = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    $select = "select * from product;";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$select);        

    if ($result) {
        $i=0;
        $outp = "";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
            $outp .= '"preis":"'   . $row["preis"]        . '",';
            $outp .= '"name":"'. $row["name"]     . '"}';
        }
        $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';

        echo($outp);
    }
 ?>
```

App.js

```
var url = "http://server/data/data.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"

    $http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.found);
    });
```

Now i get a syntax error:
"SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'"

Thanks for your help

Comment: "I read that i have to use jsonp, elsewhise i will not get the data." — No. You need to do *something* to work around the Same Origin Policy if you want to do Ajax across origins. JSONP is a dirty hack that achieves that. We have CORS now. Use CORS.

Comment: Do not generate JSON by mashing strings together manually. PHP has had [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) for ages.

Comment: Now I use the json_encode and it looks like the SyntaxError is gone.
But I get a 404 Error when I run the js...
Even the php reports the correct data. I can put my url in for example https://jsonformatter.org/. And it says it's a valid json.
The question you linked in here as the duplicate is not helping me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: 404 just means you got the URL wrong on top of any other problems you have.

Comment: But i can reach the url. That's why i wonder, why it says 404...

Answer (score 0):

Don't build JSON by yourself. Try this instead. Main thing is, just create an array the way you'd like it, then use `json_encode()`

```
$result = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: This helped me for the moment. It looks like the json Object is now correct.
But I always get an 404 error. looks like i can't reach the data. But I can open the url in my browser and I can see the data.